# Using DeleteCases for twitter messages using the timestamp

Tags: string-manipulation, text

I have a Excelsheet with tweetsmessages. These tweets are all written in Dutch.  I would like to analyse these tweets in relation to the timestamp.

```
tweets = Import["E:\\mathematica\\data\\tweets_gr2014_v5.xls", {"Data", 1}];

tweets[[2 ;;, {1, 2}]]
```

The result is : The result is: 
{
  {"19-3-2014 23:13", "##GR2014 - Een goeie in tv commentaar: #Wilders schreeuwt wel veel, maar hij wil helemaal niet in steden regeren. Hij doet bijna nergens mee"}, 
  {"19-3-2014 21:49", "#020kiest eerste uitslag Amsterdam zo op AT5 #GR2014 #at5"}, 
  {"19-3-2014 22:26", "#033kiest pvda verliest veel... was wel te verwachten nietwaar? #GR2014"}.......}

Then I use StringCases to split the individual words in the tweet messages.

```
tweets1 = Transpose@{tweets[[2 ;;, 1]],  StringCases[ToLowerCase[tweets[[2 ;;,
 2]]], RegularExpression["\\w(?<!\\d)[\\w'-]*"]]};
```

The next step is dat I would like tot delete all stop words. Therefor I have a listing with Dutch Stop words.

stopwoordenNL = { "aan", "al", "alles", "als", "altijd", "andere",    "ben", "bij", "daar", "dan", "dat", "de", "der", "deze", "die",    "dit", "doch", "doen", "door", "dus", "een", "eens", "en", "er",    "ge", "geen", "geweest", "haar", "had", "heb", "hebben", "heeft", 
"hem", "het", "hier", "hij", "hoe", "hun", "iemand", "iets", "ik",    "in", "is", "ja", "je", "kan", "kon", "kunnen", "maar", "me",    "meer", "men", "met", "mij", "mijn", "moet", "na", "naar", "niet",    "niets", "nog", "nu", "of", "om", "omdat", "onder", "ons", "ook", 
"op", "over", "reeds", "te", "tegen", "toch", "toen", "tot", "u",    "uit", "uw", "van", "veel", "voor", "want", "waren", "was", "wat",    "werd", "wezen", "wie", "wil", "worden", "wordt", "zal", "ze",    "zelf", "zich", "zij", "zijn", "zo", "zonder", "zou", "ten", "per",
"lid", "pagina", "toe", "indien", "alle", "den", "bent", "hebt",    "nee", "ja", "wel", "mee", "ter", "zie", "aldus", "alsmede",    "alsnog", "betreffende", "danwel", "derhalve", "zoals", "zowel",    "hierbij", "hierboven", "hiermee", "hierna", "hiertoe", "hiervan",    "hiervoor", "tenzij", "and", "for"};

Without using the timestamp I used the script:

```
DeleteCases[tweets[[All, 2]], w_ /; MemberQ[stopwoordenNL], ToLowerCase[w]]];
```

But it doesn't work when I analyse two columns. How can I delete the stop words?

Comment: The problem is most likely that `w_` matches the top level, i.e. your list of lists. You have to make the pattern more specific, like this: `{___,{___,w_,___},___}`, or you can add `Level[w_] = ...` where `...` is the appropriate level to your condition.

Comment: Michiel, your final step is to use `DeleteCases` on `tweets[[All, 2]]`. Do you not mean to do something with `tweets1` instead? There is also a syntax error in your last line, you probably meant to place the square bracket that closes `MemberQ` after `ToLowerCase[w]`. I'm not sure how the timestamp is relevant to all this, let's try to focus on deleting the "stop woorden" first, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's make some data first

```
str1 = Import["http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kat_(dier)", 
   "Plaintext"];
str2 = Import["http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hond", "Plaintext"];
```

This is a shorter way to get the words

```
words1 = StringCases[str, WordCharacter ..];
words2 = StringCases[str2, WordCharacter ..];
```

We could now immediately delete the "stopwoorden"

```
katNonStop = DeleteCases[words1, Alternatives @@ stopwoordenNL];
hondNonStop = DeleteCases[words2, Alternatives @@ stopwoordenNL];
```

But let's try to remake the structure of `tweets1`

```
tweets1 = {{{"bla1"}, words1}, {{"bla2"}, words2}};
```

We could then do

```
DeleteCases[tweets1[[All, 2]], Alternatives @@ stopwoordenNL, Infinity]
```

Comment: Hi Jacob,Thanks for your answer. When I try the same logic for SringReplace I've got a error:'String or list of strings expected at position 1 in StringReplace'. Can you explain me why?  tweets3 = 
 StringReplace[tweets2[[All, 2]], 
  Alternatives @@ Characters[punctuation] -> " ", Infinity]

Comment: I forgot to write that punctuation = ",/.<>?;':\"()+-_!&";

Comment: @MichielvanMens You are welcome. Try `StringReplace[#, Alternatives @@ Characters[punctuation] -> " "] & /@ 
 tweets2[[All, 2]]`.

Comment: Great!! Thank you.